# Mysql, query to return all rows for an item if sales date within past X days

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have the following type of table, named item_sales:

```
Item, Sales_Date, Num_Sold
--------------------------
item1, 2015-01-02, 500
item1, 2016-01-03, 350
item1, 2017-01-21, 450
item2, 2015-01-02, 750
item2, 2015-01-03, 1100
item2, 2016-01-04, 1000
item3, 2017-01-02, 200
item3, 2017-01-03, 100
item3, 2017-02-04, 100
```

Im trying to figure out how to return all the rows for a given item, if its had a Sale within the past 90 days.  Its easy to return or find a given item with group by, but I'm not sure how to say give me all the records for item1 and item3 if the max(sales_date) >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 90 day)

The output from the correct query should be:

```
Item, Sales_Date, Num_Sold
--------------------------
item1, 2015-01-02, 500
item1, 2016-01-03, 350
item1, 2017-01-21, 450
item3, 2017-01-02, 200
item3, 2017-01-03, 100
item3, 2017-02-04, 100
```

Comment: Have sub-query that returns each item's last sale date. Join with that result.

Comment: Can you provide an example?